# Converting string[][][] to string[][] in f#

Tags: sorting, f#, type-conversion

I'm having some troubles with F# because i'm learning. I have something like the next code:

```
let A = [| [| [|"1";"Albert"|];[|"2";"Ben"|] |];[| [|"1";"Albert"|];[|"3";"Carl"|] |] |]
```

(Type A: `string[][][]`)

I'm trying to convert A to:

```
let B = [| [|"1"; "Albert" |] ; [| "2"; "Ben"|] ; [| "3"; "Carl"|] |]
```

(Type B: `string[][]`)

I don't know how to do this. I've been trying some `for` and recursive function but I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Array.concat` to turn the `string[][][]` into `string[][]`, and then `Seq.distinct` to remove the duplicate string arrays.

```
let b = 
    [| [| [|"1";"Albert"|];[|"2";"Ben"|] |];[| [|"1";"Albert"|];[|"3";"Carl"|] |] |]
        |> Array.concat
        |> Seq.distinct
        |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of other options for implementing this to help you conceptualize this type of problem better:

```
let A = [| [| [|"1";"Albert"|];[|"2";"Ben"|] |];[| [|"1";"Albert"|];[|"3";"Carl"|] |] |]

//Matthew's answer
//This is exactly what you were asking for.  
//It takes all the subarrays and combines them into one
A |> Array.concat
  |> Seq.distinct
  |> Seq.toArray

//This is the same thing except it combines it with a transformation step, 
//although in your case, the transform isn't needed so the transform 
//function is simply `id`
A |> Seq.collect id
  |> Seq.distinct
  |> Seq.toArray

//The same as the second one except using a comprehension.  
//This form makes it somewhat more clear exactly what is happening (iterate 
//the items in the array and yield each item).
//The equivalent for the first one is `[|for a in A do yield! a|]`
[for a in A do for b in a -> b] 
|> Seq.distinct
|> Seq.toArray
```